# equivalent to Ubuntu's apport-bug in Fedora or Mint?

Tags: ubuntu, fedora

What is the Fedora equivalent to the Ubuntu command apport-bug to submit bug reports?

In Ubuntu, one can use:

```
apport-bug <package-name>
```

For example:

```
apport-bug xorg
```

To submit bug reports that include all the logs and relevant information about the system. What is the equivalent in Fedora? How about Mint?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fedora uses [ABRT](https://fedorahosted.org/abrt/wiki) instead, which doesn't have quite the same capability. Mint, based on Ubuntu, should already have apport.