# Does Mint Linux have apport-bug for bug reporting?

Tags: linux-mint

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [equivalent to Ubuntu's apport-bug in Fedora or Mint?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/19099/equivalent-to-ubuntus-apport-bug-in-fedora-or-mint)

Can a Linux Mint user report a bug using apport-bug like in Ubuntu Linux? For example:

```
apport-bug <package-name>
```